# error MSB4025: не удалось загрузить файл проекта. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. Ошибка сборки

Tags: c#, linux, .net, visual-studio-code

При сборке проекта произошла ошибка.

```
/home/katerina/aur/visual-studio-code-bin/HelloWorld/program.cs(1,1): error MSB4025: не удалось загрузить файл проекта. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. Ошибка сборки. Устраните ошибки сборки и повторите попытку.
```

[image: error]
Пробовала изменить содержание файла `settings.json` на:

```
{
    "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

Не вышло. Жду ваших предложений.

> UPD: Решила проблему командой `dotnet new console`. Далее `dotnet run`

Comment: `.cs` - файл C# кода, `.csproj` - файл проекта, `.sln` - файл решения (группа проектов). Вы указываете `dotnet run --project ... .cs`, подумайте теперь, то ли вы пытаетесь запустить?